# Cron job not running at custom time setting

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, dreamhost

I have a WordPress application which is hosted on DreamHost. I'm currently running a cron job under my DreamHost account which will visit a template every 5 minutes. The current cron time settings look something like this:

[image]

I expect this cron job to execute every five minutes. However, it seems to  be running every one hour, since I only get a report on my email address after every one hour.

What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: Hint: _Hold ctrl (...) to select multiple values_ . It works properly, it does not say "every 5 minutes", it implies "at 5th minute".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to select "Interval Minutes" of something like that instead of "Selected minutes"?

Otherwise you have to select `0, 5, 10, 15, 20, ... and 55` in your select box. Multiselect should be possible.

Comment: There is no Interval Minutes on the DreamHost Panel. He'll have to manually select like you said `0, 5, 10, 15, 20, ... and 55` and that will run the cron every 5 minutes, unless instead he chooses the "once every 10 minutes" in the "minutes" drop down there is no 5 minute though.